# can't figure out type

Tags: apex

What am i doing wrong?

```
List <Account> test1 = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 99];
for (Account test2 : test1) {
    System.debug(test2);
    System.debug(test1[test2.Id]);
}
```

I get error "Compile failure on line 4, column 18: List index must be of type Integer: Id"
How can i call specific object from a list of objects by the id of the iterations of the same list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test1` is a `List`.

So to access a `List` element you must pass an integer. Orelse you will get `List index must be of type Integer: Id`

Why do you want to do this. `System.debug(test1[test2.Id]);`

You are already iterating on the list itself.

If you want to get the account based on ID. You can use something like this.

```
List <Account> test1 = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 99];
Map <Id, Account> secondListOfAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 99]);
for (Account test2 : test1) {
    System.debug(test2);
    System.debug(secondListOfAccounts.get(test2.Id));
}
```

Comment: No point in executing the query twice (even in examples). Iterate over map.values

Comment: Its just example of how we can use map to get values. Ofcourse we can iterate over values too, But just showing a way to fetch values from other account map, not the same map.

Answer (score 0):

Index can't be accessed in the For each loop, you'll have to use the traditional for loop to access index.

This :

```
for (type var : array) 
{ 
    statements using var;
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
{ 
    type var = arr[i];
    statements using var;
}
```

- For each loops don't keep track of the index

Comment: Please add comments on why the answer was downvoted. This downvote doesn't help

Comment: I think iterating over map instead of list is the correct (and easiest) solution for my problem.  Thank you all